# How to Identify in which cloud platform my flask app is running?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, google-cloud-platform

Im having a flask application which needs to be deployed to aws and gcp.And based on the cloud platform I need to changed certain environment.Is there any way to identify in which cloud my python script is running ? I have tried

```
 import socket
 socket.gethostname()
```

But that is too generic.Is there anyway to create a validation to identify the cloud platform with python ?

Answer (score 5):

Every cloud provider usually sets a bunch of environment variables that are specific to them and those variables usually have the cloud provider initials as prefix. You can use those variables to identify the cloud provider.

Or,

You can use this package - https://pypi.org/project/cloud-detect/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what am exactly looking for !